# What are the issues with adding Craft Commerce to an existing Craft CMS site?

Tags: ecommerce

We are about to start on a project that will include a complex product catalogue, with multiple product categories and loads of relationships. The client has stated that they may want to create an online store to sell catalogue items at some point in the future.

The thought at this point is to create the product catalogue using standard Craft CMS features like Structures and Categories. Anyone have any experience or guidance on adding Craft Commerce to an existing Craft site? Will I have to recreate product structures or can build the initial version in a manner that allows Craft Commerce to work with an existing product schema?

Answer (score 5):

You should absolutely use Craft Commerce to store the products, as there is no migration from Entries -> Craft Commerce products.

You don’t need to pay for a Craft Commerce license if you are not utilizing a payment gateway, so there is really no downside to getting things into Commerce in the first place, and plenty of downside to needing it and not having it already in Commerce down the road.

Comment: Thank you! That answers my question and also provides the perfect way forward - did not realize a license was not required for use without a payment gateway. Much appreciated!